# skimage: Why does rgb2gray from skimage.color result in a colored image?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

When I tried to convert the image to gray scale using:

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
mountain_r = rgb2gray(imread(os.getcwd() + '/mountain.jpg'))

#Plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(0)
plt.imshow(mountain_r)
plt.show()
```

I got a weird colored image instead of a gray scale.

Manually implementing the function also gives me the same result. The custom function is:

```
def rgb2grey(rgb):
    if len(rgb.shape) is 3:
        return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])

    else:
        print 'Current image is already in grayscale.'
        return rgb
```

[image: Original]

Coloured image that is not in greyscale.
[image: gray]

Why doesn't the function convert the image to greyscale?

Comment: The grayscale-conversion is working correctly, but matplotlib is just using another colormap by default, where not shades of grey, but something between blue and red is chosen. Try ```imshow(cmap='Greys')```. You can check the output and will see, that the lightest parts of the image are currently red, the darkest are blue.

Comment: That was very helpful. My image is in greyscale now.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The resulting image is in grayscale. However, `imshow`, by default, uses a kind of heatmap (called viridis) to display the image intensities. Just specify the grayscale colormap as shown below:

`plt.imshow(mountain_r, cmap="gray")`

For all the possible colormaps, have a look at the [colormap reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html).